# Cannot run math on numbers from array; "integer expression expected"

Tags: bash

```
if [ "${INSTANCE_NUMBER[$i]}" -ge 1 ]
```

returns `[: 1,: integer expression expected`

`INSTANCE_NUMBER` is an array of number, assigned like so:

```
INSTANCE_NUMBER=(1, 1, 1)
```

I'm puzzled why it's returning this.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `$INSTANCE_NUMBER` please?

Comment: In the future, include the assignment in your question -- that is, show us exactly how you're setting `INSTANCE_NUMBER`; otherwise, your reproducer isn't complete.

Comment: Post `echo ${INSTANCE_NUMBER[@]}`

Comment: @Cyrus, FWIW, `printf '%q\n' "${INSTANCE_NUMBER[@]}"` would be better; can't distinguish element boundaries in output from `echo`. That said, I'm certain that Barmar has the right of it.

Comment: printf '%q\n' "${INSTANCE_NUMBER[@]}" prints:1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: @PedroTanaka, ...then you don't have `1 2 3 4` [...] in your array, but just `1 1 1 1`. We can't help with that without information you didn't provide, and anyhow, it should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign an array, don't put commas between the elements, just spaces:

```
INSTANCE_NUMBER=(1 2 3)
```

The comma is becoming part of the array elements, so they're not valid numbers.

Comment: It solves the error but it then prints 0 to n when it should be printing 1 to n.

Comment: @PedroTanaka Array indexes start from `0`. You either need to fix how you set `$i`, or substract 1 from it when using it as an index.

Comment: that solves it; thx; will resolve when stackoverflow allows me